# How to save PHPUnit tests as individual TAP results

Tags: php, unit-testing, jenkins, phpunit, tap

I have a jenkins setup that runs some unit tests with PHPUnit.

I would like each unit testcase to be saved as a separate tap result file.

E.g. the results of `testOneTest.php` and `testTwoTest.php` will be saved as `testOneTest.tap` and `testTwoTest.tap` respectively. This presents build results much better in the Jenkins UI.

I have defined an [XML configuration file](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html) for PHPUnit, but from the documentation, I can only see the option to save as a single tap result file:

`<log type="tap" target="/tmp/logfile.tap"/>`

Is it possible to save multiple TAP results?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [XML configuration files](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html), just create two different configuration files with different output names. Depending on how you invoke phpunit, then it could look like this:

```
1> phpunit -c /your/xml/configfile1.xml testOneTest.php
2> phpunit -c /your/xml/configfile2.xml testTwoTest.php
```

You also could just give the output parameter to phpunit:

```
1> phpunit --log-tap /tmp/logfile1.tap testOneTest.php
2> phpunit --log-tap /tmp/logfile2.tap testTwoTest.php
```

Comment: Thanks Bjoern. I could try it for now, but I find this quite an ugly solution... I'd have to have a separate xml config for every unit testcase? If I have a couple of hundred unit tests it would mean managing a couple of hundred xml files too.

Comment: Therefore you'd have to have some kind of variable in the xml file. I don't think phpunit currently supports something like this. If it was me, I'd write a shell script which invokes phpunit like the second example - or, split the tap file after it was created.